# rando guessing game in python

Tags: function, python-3.x, random

My code was working fine. if I'm not using the function then the programs work how it should. When I have the function it is telling me variable number is not defined. I tried defining the variable as 0 or 1, but then it ends up making my number 0 or 1. Keep in mind that this is for school. Suggestions would be helpful, thanks!

```
import random

easy = random.randint (1,20)
medium = random.randint (1,50)
hard = random.randint (1,100)
guessesTaken = 0

name = input("Hello, What is your name? ")

def difficulties():
    difficulty = input("Well, ",name,". What dificulty would you like ?       easy, medium, or hard? ")
    if difficulty == "easy":
        number = easy
        print ("Okay, ",name,". I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20")
    if difficulty == "medium":
        number = medium
        print ("Okay, ",name,". I am thinking of a number between 1 and 50")
    if difficulty == "hard":
        number = hard
        print ("Okay, ",name,". I am thinking of a number between 1 and  100")

difficulties()

while guessesTaken < 6:
    guess = int(input('Take a guess. ')) 
    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too low.") 

    if guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too high.")

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str (guessesTaken)
    print("Good job, ",name," ! You guessed my number in ",guessesTaken," guesses, good job!")

if guess != number:
    number = str (number)
    print("Nope. The number I was thinking of was ",number,", better luck next time!")
```

Comment: "is causing me some issues" is too ambiguous. Please post the exact issues you are facing.

Comment: My bad, if I'm not using the function then the programs work how it should. When I have the function it is telling me variable number is not defined.

Comment: Thanks, please add that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is saying that `number` is not defined is because it is a local variable of `difficulties()`. To fix this problem, in the `difficulties()` function, after the `difficulty` input, just type

`global number`

This makes `number` a `global` variable, which allows it to be referenced outside of the `difficulties()` function.
Hope this helps!